# Modifying plain text inside div without modifying the inner span

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, html

I have div nodes like

```
<div> Text <span class="required">*</span></div>
```

and

```
<div> Text </div>
```

I want to convert them into

```
<div> <a href="some target">Text</a><span class="required">*</span></div>
```

and

```
<div> <a href="some target">Text</a></div>
```

How I achieve this using JavaScript (regex?) or jQuery

Comment: Please share the markup as well, just to be clear

Answer (score 1):

Maybe someone will have a better solution (I hope and look forward to)

Provided you know your structure is going to be like that, this should work just fine:

```
$(function(){    
    var html = $('div').html();
    var fixed = html.substring(html.indexOf('<span'), html.length);
    var toWrap = html.substring(0, html.indexOf('<span'));
    var newHtml = '<a href="sometarget">'+toWrap+'</a>'+fixed;
    $('div').html(newHtml);
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/asZNZ/)